# Sass Mixin to use SVG as background and change color

Tags: css, svg, sass, mixins

I would to use SVG as background and to be able to change is color via a css way.
So after searching, I found this thread but I'm not sure about where to place the svg url in my mixin.

[SVG as a background-image in MIXIN setting color via a SASS variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896368/svg-as-a-background-image-in-mixin-setting-color-via-a-sass-variable)

My starting point:

```
$imagedir:'../images/'; // definir ici le chemin vers le dossier image
@mixin backgroundSVGandColor($filename,$color:red) {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='#{$imagedir}#{$filename}'><g stroke="#{$color}" ... /></g></svg>');

}
```

But what'is this "g" element ? Should it contain my svg url ?

Thanks

EDIT: new version for my mixin, inspired by yours comments

```
@mixin backgroundSVGandColor($filename,$color:red) {
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<'svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" "'#{$imagedir}#{$filename}",{$color}'></svg>");

    }
```

is the URI is in the right place ?

EDIT2: new version

```
   @mixin backgroundSVGandColor($filename,$color:red) {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="url('#{$imagedir}#{$filename}')" color='$color');

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to apply styling adjustments purely through CSS to an SVG that is loaded through a URL, whether it is loaded in your HTML through `img[src]` or in your `CSS` through `url('https://image-path')`

In order to change the SVG's style purely through CSS, it must be *inlined*, either in the HTML, or in the way your mixin does it through a data-URI.

---

#### Styling SVGs in HTML

SVGs are an XML-based markup language.

SVG markup is considered valid HTML, so the file-content of a `.svg` file can be copied and pasted directly into your HTML document.

This means you do not necessarily have to load the svg using `img[src]` in the HTML, and by having the contents directly in HTML, you can apply CSS styles to it with CSS selectors.

---

#### Styling SVGs in CSS

As your mixin demonstrates, the contents of the SVG have been copied and pasted in as a [data-URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). Take some [special care](https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/) to include the correct encoding and to escape strange characters to ensure the browser correctly interprets the data representing your SVG image.

---

#### About svg xmlns attribute

There is a problem with this bit of code in your current mixin:

```
<svg xmlns='#{$imagedir}#{$filename}'>
```

This `xmlns` attribute is **not** used as a path to your svg image! It is used to tell the browser [how to interpret the XML tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course) used in the SVG, so it should point to the standard `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`

Answer (score 0):

Its easy, but the function needs other parameter, have $filename and $color but need $imagedir, It should be like this:

```
backgroundSVGandColor($imagedir,$filename,$color:red)...
```

`$filename` is the name of your svg file
`$imagedir` is the path of your svg file
`$color` is obvious...

In SASS you can access to the variables content with: `#{$varName}`

The `<g>` tag is for agroup objects, you can learn about that in this link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g

Comment: Thanks, but where do I put my url with this particular syntax ?

Comment: backgroundSVGandColor('./assets/imgs/','image.svg',#c0c0c0)

If the answer is correct, please check me.